# pass GLOBIGNORE to a bash invocation

Tags: bash, environment-variables, glob

The [`bash` manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) states

```
If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to
the real user (group) id, [...] the  SHELLOPTS,  BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and
GLOBIGNORE variables if they appear in the environment, are ignored
```

So normally this happens.

```
> export GLOBIGNORE='*t*'
> echo *
afile
> bash -i
>> # look, the variable is passed through
>> $ echo $GLOBIGNORE
*t*
>> # but to no effect
>> $ echo *
afile anotherfile athirdfile
```

I do not think it would make much sense to fake the real user id to enable passing `GLOBIGNORE` and a number of other unwanted side-effects.

Is it possibile to make the subshell respect an exported `GLOBIGNORE`?

Answer (score 1):

Some other shell hacks may come to the rescue. All these solutions require at least to modify the shell invocation, but make the subshell start readily prepared.

As shell startup is different on interactive shells, two strategies are needed.

## Interactive

When starting an interactive session, bash normally sources the default `~/.bashrc` file. There is a switch to change where to look for this file. This can be exploited without loss as long as the script passed in there redirects to the original location.

```
> echo 'GLOBIGNORE=*t*' > rc
> echo 'source ~/.bashrc' >> rc
> bash --rcfile rc -i
>> echo *
```

## Non-Interactive, Modifyable Command String

[As Cyrus already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528338/1018226), one could simply augment the command with the assignment so that it happens inside the subshell to begin with.

```
> bash -c 'GLOBIGNORE="*t*" ; echo *'
```

## Fully Automated

If modification of the passed commands should be avoided, another special variable can be employed. It is called `BASH_ENV` and denotes a script to source when starting up a non-interactive session. With this, a strategy similar to `--rcfile` arises.

```
> echo 'GLOBIGNORE=*t*' > rc
> BASH_ENV=rc bash -c "echo *"
```

Or, to be even more sleazy and avoid the temporary file `rc`, we can force piping, which is clearly not intended as the value `-` is not regarded as the standard input.

```
> echo 'GLOBIGNORE=*t*' | BASH_ENV=/dev/stdin bash -c "echo *"
```